# Sending data using esp_now

Tags: c, esp32, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

Normally when I send and receive data using a `send_now` I use a structure as in this tutorial [code](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp-now-one-to-many-esp32-esp8266/). In this way, I face a problem, which is declaring an array where I need to declare size inside the structure to ensure that the sending and receiving process is done correctly. While sometimes I need to send an array I don't know what its size is, for example, this array

```
  double *arry=(double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
```

So can I send without using struct? or can I declare the arry[] inside struct without its size? and then specify it size?

sender struct:

```
typedef struct test_struct {
  int arry[];  I need to send this array but I do not know its size yet
} test_struct;
```

receiver struct:

```
typedef struct test_struct {
  int arry[];
} test_struct;
```

UPDATE:
I trying to like this but I received uncorrect values
in sender

```
int sizee=100;
double *by=(double*)malloc(sizee*sizeof(double));
  for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
       by[i]=i;
       Serial.println(by[i]);
  }
  esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(0, (uint8_t *) &by, sizeof(double));
```

In receiver

```
int sizee=100;
  double *by=(double*)malloc(sizee*sizeof(double));
  Serial.print("rearray=: ");
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    Serial.print(by[i]);
}
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Well, the size of that array is `size*sizeof(double)`, right?  You will just need to keep that data and pass that information around whenever you deal with that array.  It doesn't matter that it's not a struct.  It's all just memory.  Right?

Comment: Side note: this looks a lot like C code rather than C++ and in C you can define an array without specifying the size of the array. In C++ the size of everything must always be known at compile time.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Yes its dynamic allocation could you see the update

Comment: Of course you received the wrong data.  You allocate `by`, then you fill and send `arry`.  Is  that a typo?  We don't know what `arry` is.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Sorry, I update the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply trying to send 100 double-precision floats, this will do it:

```
int sizee=100;
double *by=(double*)malloc(sizee*sizeof(double));

for (int i=0; i < sizee; i++) {
    by[i]=i;
    Serial.println(by[i]);
}
esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(0, (uint8_t *) by, sizee*sizeof(double));
```

The receiver has to be a callback, right?  Something like this:

```
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac_addr, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len) {
  double *by=(double*)incomingData;
  Serial.print("rearray=: ");
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    Serial.print(by[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

I don't know whether `Serial.print` can handle doubles.  You'll have to check that.

Comment: Yes, I did that but I get on E (218) ESPNOW: Invalid argument! Error sending the data . That happen because with 100 and double I have big size and send_now did not sand more than 250 bytes :( .. I will give you the best answer for  sizee*sizeof(double)  but you need to use &by :)

Comment: So now I trying to send by using wifi because I have more than 250 bytes. So I will open new question

Comment: Yes.  You need to ask yourself if you really need doubles here.  Just moving to single precision floats cuts your transmission in half.